# BasicAuth with "ldap file" providers doesn't work for users in file

Tags: apache, server, ldap, basic-authentication, apache2.2

I have a host where authenticated users need to be in a certain ldap group. This worked perfectly. Afterwards I needed an external user that I put locally in a file and this one doesn't work.

When I comment out all the ldap lines that user works, so the file is created correctly and accessible by Apache 2.2, but when I add ldap, everything work for the ldap users but not for the file user.

When I try to log in with the local in file user with a bad password I get the log in pop-up again, as usual, but when I insert the correct credentials I get "**Authorization Required**
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

Below is my set upon Apache 2.2

```
        <Location "/">
            Deny from all

            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "My Auth"
            AuthBasicProvider ldap file
            AuthLDAPURL LDAP_URL
            AuthUserFile "path/to/pass/file"

            Require user file_user
            Require ldap-group cn=LDAP Group,cn=Groups,dc=DC,dc=org
            Require ldap-user ldap_user_outside_group

            Satisfy any
    </Location>
```

Comment: Is your user present in LDAP but with a different password, or absent from LDAP entirely?

Comment: it is absent from LDAP. It is totally new user that I added only for testing purposes in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need `AuthzLDAPAuthoritative` to allow the failure to match the ldap-based Require directives to not be fatal.  This kind of directive was made obsolete in later releases by internal improvements in 2.4.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.